# UIView movement

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewanimation

Which is the best way to move a UIView.
I have a custom UIView with some custom things in it, like shadows, labels  etc.

Today I'm using, for move this UIView.:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (self.isEditing) {       
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[rootView view]];      
        self.center = location; 
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to move a UIView? I experience this a bit laggy.

Comment: there are various ways to animate a view,it depends how you want to move a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually reposition a view using the offset between the touchesBegan location and the touchesMoves location.